# Can the study of finite-dimensional inner product spaces be reduced to the study of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I'm trying to understand the role that orthonormal basis have, and I come across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) passage:

> For a general inner product space $V$, an orthonormal basis can be used to define normalized orthogonal coordinates on $V$. Under these coordinates, the inner product becomes a dot product of vectors. Thus the presence of an orthonormal basis reduces the study of a finite-dimensional inner product space to the study of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under dot product. Every finite-dimensional inner product space has an orthonormal basis, which may be obtained from an arbitrary basis using the Gram–Schmidt process.

and I am trying to digest what this means. I'll try and break it down by the real and complex vector spaces, and see where that leads me.

[image]

So $\varphi$ is a [unitary transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_transformation), so I could see how

> "...the presence of an orthonormal basis reduces the study of a [***real***] finite-dimensional inner product space to the study of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under dot product"

makes sense.

[image]

So $\psi$ is a [unitary transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_transformation), hence I could ***also*** see how

> "...the presence of an orthonormal basis reduces the study of a [***complex***] finite-dimensional inner product space to the study of $\require{cancel}\cancel{\mathbb{R}^n} \ \mathbb{C}^n$ under <del>dot product</del> *complex dot product*"

makes sense. So it could just be that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) passage is "shorthand" for these two conclusions together. That's the simplest interpretation.

But it could also be that, they actually ***do*** mean that "the presence of an orthonormal basis reduces the study of a [***complex***] finite-dimensional inner product space to the study of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under dot product"; I attempted to figure out how that would possible - my intuition being that if $H \cong \mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ then maybe $H \cong \mathbb{R}$??

Lets say we have $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with the standard (complex) basis and *complex* dot product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\mathbb{C}^n}:\mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$. I know that $\mathbb{C}^n$ could also be viewed as a *real* vector space, and it's standard (*real*) basis would just be:

[image]

and it's (*real*) inner product would be:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\mathbb{C}^n(\mathbb{R})}: \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}; &&&
(\pmb u, \pmb v) \mapsto \operatorname{Re}(\langle \pmb u, \pmb v \rangle_{\mathbb{C}^n})   .
\end{align}
$$
So when viewing $\mathbb{C}^n$ a *real* vector space, I could define a mapping to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard basis and dot product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^n}:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ - that map being:
$$
\newcommand{\iu}{{\mathrm{i}\mkern 1mu}}
\begin{align}
\chi: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}; 
&&& (a_{1}+\iu b_{1}, a_{2}+\iu b_{2}, \dots, a_{n}+\iu b_{n}) \mapsto (a_{1},b_{1},a_{2},b_{2},\dots,a_{n},b_{n}). 
\end{align}
$$
I know that that $\chi$ is linear and bijective (*proof too long, didn't include*), and also:
[image]

So $\chi$ is *also* a [unitary transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_transformation), meaning $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ are isomorphic as *real* inner product spaces. But that kinda breaks the intuition I had *earlier*, since its not obvious that $H$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ are isomorphic as *real* inner product spaces. And even if they were, I don't see how the study of $H$ can be reduced to the study of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ under the dot product.

I think my first (and the simplest) interpretation is correct. Is this so?

Comment: A real-linear isomorphism between $\mathbf{C}^{m}$ and $\mathbf{R}^{2m}$ and a real inner product on $\mathbf{R}^{2m}$ do not generally determine an Hermitian inner product on $\mathbf{C}^{m}$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, they mean the study of finite-dimensional real inner product spaces reduces to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the dot product, and the study of finite-dimensional complex inner product spaces reduces to $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the conjugate-transpose inner product. Their study is parallel in many ways but different in others. For instance, self-adjoint matrices over $\mathbb{R}^n$ are symmetric matrices, and these form an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, but self-adjoint matrices over $\mathbb{C}^n$ do not form a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space.